# Get/Set Variable

Tags: c#

the goal of the program is to be able to use the get and set methods of variables.

I have this code in a project C#:

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int c = 0;
    public int a { get; set; }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a = 5;
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.b = a;
        f2.Show();
    }
}
}
```

and in a Form2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();



        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(b));
    }
}
}
```

This code not work because the value of b should be 5, but during execution value 0;

any solution?

Comment: It's only set to 5 when you click the button in `Form1`. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, but you might want to limit your project to a single form to avoid confusion.

Comment: You create a new instance of form1, and call a get of this new instance... the default value for this is 0

Comment: You probably need a `f1.a = 5` after you instantiate a new instance of Form1. By default, it will be initialized to 0. You are setting it 5 only when you click the button on Form1.

Comment: I click on button1 and show new form called Form2 and i want to get value  created in Form1 to set value in a variable created in a Form2

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect values of one instance to magically propagate to every other instance.

So doing this:

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
int b = f1.a;
```

Is **always** going to be 0. You created a new instance, and nothing has happened to it! If you want to get the *existing* form's value (where the button was presumably clicked) you need to pass it to Form2 somehow.

You can:

- Pass it on the constructor of `Form2`
- Set up a service that holds the data instead
- Probably about a million other approaches

Comment: can report an example?

Comment: @CristianMagrini Do some research, examples are only in a million other places on the web (and even on SO). If you have a more specific question than that, feel free to ask.

Comment: I have posted my code but still not work, and i try a solution if you have a solution post it

Comment: @CristianMagrini Don't get me wrong *I know what you are trying to do*. I could write an entire program to do it in about 5 minutes (if that) But seriously, just giving you a pre-made solution (especially when there really are a *ton* of examples out there) doesn't truly help you. Did you try googling "pass on constructor" or "pass value between forms c#"?

Comment: By the way, your current code doesn't make sense. `b` is not defined on Form2

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a = 5;
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.b=a;
    f2.Show();
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
public int b;
    public Form2()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

You want to pass the data before showing the second form instead of after the fact.